# Image color cloning using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to clone the image color. So far I have done with creating the mask and color it but I am getting the solid color of the image but I was expecting the output like this

[image: Image Link]

```
    def colorchange(self):
        res = self.image_m_c              #Original Image
        copyimg = np.copy(res)

        r = self.t5.value()               #R,G,B Channel using slider
        g = self.t6.value()
        b = self.t7.value()

        copyimg = cv2.cvtColor(copyimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        img = self.new_image              #Mask of the image


        copyimg[img!=0]=(b,g,r) #Coloring the mask

        copyimg = cv2.cvtColor(copyimg, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        cv2.imshow("IMAGE",copyimg)
```